# Python Ram usage increases after new thread starts

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

In a True while loop, I'm starting a new Thread which in turn starts a shell Subprocess (python script). Due to other reasons, the python scripts need to be called using the shell subprocess. The subprocess runs for a certain time and then quits.

After each thread is created the main program (cmd) requires more RAM usage.

Code for starting thread:

```
while True:
  cameras = camera_queue.get_next_cameras()
  session_id = uuid.uuid4()

  task = threading.Thread(target=start_thread, args=(cameras, f'{session_id}'))
  task.start()
  time.sleep(camera_queue.batch_size * CAMERA_INTERVAL)
```

Subprocess code (start_thread):

```
subprocess.Popen(
  f'start /MIN /wait python Backend\\Recorder\\secondary.py "{cameras}" "{logger_id}"',
  shell=True,
)
```

This program will start around 1000 subprocesses per hour. I have checked and the subprocesses do close and there never exists more subprocesses than 1000.

Is there a way to clean up the usage? If you force quit the current cmd usage the ram usage instantly disappears while the shells stay open. After running the program for 1 hour the ram usage is at 3GB and after around 10 hours around 15-20GB.

Comment: This looks like a [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), and I don't think there is much you can do about it. Since you are just executing an other python script, maybe you could change your architecture, `import` the other script at the start of you program and call its functions directly.

Comment: Why are you using a thread to start a subprocess instead of creating a subprocess directly from the main thread?

Comment: You seem to be confused between threads and [sub]processes. Also, try *join*ing the threads after you've done with them

Comment: @RolandSmith You are completely right. The thread part can be completely removed and the subprocess command can be called directly

Comment: @BlackBeans Unfortunately in this current situation, it is not possible to import the specific functions from the other script.

Comment: "The thread part can be completely removed and the subprocess command can be called directly" And if you do this, does it fix the memory problem? Separately, do you know about the `join` method of threads?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel no this did not fix it. Unfortunately because the thread is not the problem but rather the subprocess join didn't help either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@RolandSmith solution half worked. For some reason, by just passing the creation flag the scripts would never run / would instantly give a popen exception. A solution to this was to pass the shell=True still.

```
subprocess.Popen(
  ["python",
    "Backend\\Recorder\\dcr_unit.py",
    f"{cameras}",
    f"{session_id}"],
  creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
  shell=True
)
```

I noticed that for some reason the popen objects would still run in the background even though the instance was done executing its code. But when passing the creation flags and then running the script just through cmd the memory leak was pretty much 0. For some reason when running this script through a code editor like vscode would cause the memory leak tenfold. The program accumulated around 10GB of ram per 10000 new instances.

Comment: You should have mentioned that you are using vscode. It (and other IDE's) are rather *infamous* for causing problems in combination with `subprocess` or `multiprocessing`. *When in doubt, **always** check your scripts by running them directly from a terminal first.*

Comment: The original code did cause memory leak in the terminal

Comment: @RolandSmith but afterwards adding that solution it got fixed

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the threads, shell and `start`.

First, create `Popen` objects directly from the main thread.

Second, when creating subprocesses on ms-windows, there are ways to prevent/hide their windows. Since I'm not an ms-windows user, I've pulled this from the documentation;

- The first thing I would try is to specify `creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW` to prevent the process from opening a window. Note that you can use `|` to combine creationflags.
- If that doesn't work, create a `subprocess.STARTUPINFO(dwFlags=subprocess.wShowWindow, wShowWindow=subprocess.SW_HIDE)` and pass that to the `Popen` constructor.

Third, when that is done, you don't need `start` anymore, so you can also get rid of `shell=True`.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python", 
     "Backend\\Recorder\\secondary.py",
     f"{cameras}",
     f"{logger_id}"],
    creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW
)
```

[This link](https://github.com/rsmith-nl/scripts/blob/e2d7d1788bad2c40d231c118fd3b2896f7529215/dicom2png.py) points to a script that manages a herd of subprocesses. In this case they are running the `convert` program from ImageMagick, but the approach is general.

Comment: Maybe `f"{cameras}"` could be replaced entirely with `str(cameras)` or simply `cameras` if it's already a string. Similarly for `f"{logger_id}"`.

Comment: For the past days I have been trying to implement this solution but unfurtunetly the main program still has memory leak

Comment: @CasperKristiansson Try explicitly cleaning up finished `Popen` objects, as I have done in the linked schript.

Comment: @RolandSmith but how can I keep track when a Popen object is finished running?

Comment: @CasperKristiansson Use the `poll` method as demonstrated in `manageprocs` in the linked program.